# Ошибка ListView Java

Tags: java, android, listview

Есть проблема, которую не могу решить. Вот код:

```
package ru.itsln.kommunalka_android.scenarios.bill;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import ru.itsln.kommunalka_android.R;
import ru.itsln.kommunalka_android.common.MainFragment;
import ru.itsln.kommunalka_android.scenarios.billrow.billrow.BillRow;
import ru.itsln.kommunalka_android.scenarios.billrow.billrow.BillRowFragment;


public class BillFragment extends MainFragment implements BillView {

int imgCount = R.drawable.internet;
private static BillRowFragment brf;
public final static String[] data = new String[]{"Вода","Телефон","Коммуналка","Интернет"};
public final static int[] amount = new int[]{20,30,40,50};

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    ListView list = (ListView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>> img = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>(data.length);
    HashMap<String,Object> map;
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("CounterName",data[i]);
        map.put("Amount",amount[i]);
        map.put("Icon",imgCount);
        img.add(map);
    }
    String[] datas = {"CounterName","Amount","Icon"};
    int[] comp = {R.id.CounterNme,R.id.imageCounter,R.id.amount};
    final SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(),img,
            R.layout.fragment_bill,datas,comp
            );
   // final EditText editText = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.counter);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);


}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),position,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
@Override
public int getLayoutId() {
    return R.layout.fragment_bill;
}

@Override
public void setBillRow(List<BillRow> billRow) {

}

@Override
public void setOnBillRowClick(BillPresenter listener) {

}

@Override
public void setAddBillRow() {

}
```

}

Я мог бы использовать ListAdapter, но не могу, так как мешает этот код:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ViewManager {

private MainPresenter mainPresenter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mainPresenter = new MainPresenter(this);
}

@Override
public void show(Presenter presenter) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.main_content, presenter.getView().getFragment());
    transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
}

@Override
public void showLongNotify(String message) {
    Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void showShortNotify(String message) {
    Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

Вот XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageCounter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/internet" >
    </ImageView>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/CounterNme"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:text="TextView" >

    </TextView>
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/amount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:text="TextView" >

    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Код ошибки:

```
11-08 17:06:20.781  13070-13070/ru.itsln.kommunalka_android E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: ru.itsln.kommunalka_android, PID: 13070
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {ru.itsln.kommunalka_android/ru.itsln.kommunalka_android.scenarios.main.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2986)
        at
android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3017)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
        at ru.itsln.kommunalka_android.scenarios.bill.BillFragment.onActivityCreated(BillFragment.java:47)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1973)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1103)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1259)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1624)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:330)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onResume(FragmentActivity.java:441)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1257)
        at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6076)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2975)
```

UPD_0:

код MainFragment:

```
public abstract class MainFragment extends Fragment implements CommonView {
    protected View view;
    private Map<Integer, View> components = new HashMap<>();
    private CreateViewListener createViewListener;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(getLayoutId(), container, false);
        if (createViewListener != null) createViewListener.onCreateView();
        return view;
    }

    protected abstract int getLayoutId();

    private View findView(int id) {
        if (!components.containsKey(id)) {
            components.put(id, view.findViewById(id));
        }
        return components.get(id);
    }

    protected TextView getTextView(int id) { return (TextView) findView(id); }

    protected Button getButton(int id) { return (Button) findView(id); }

    @Override
    public Fragment getFragment() {
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public void setOnCreateViewListener(CreateViewListener listener) { createViewListener = listener; }

}
```

Comment: А MainFragment это ListFragment?

Comment: нет, просто Fragment

Comment: Значит вы просто не тот id указали вашему ListView. Тут `ListView list = (ListView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);` надо пространство имён андроида убрать. И проверить, что в разметке id верный стоит.

Comment: В этом случае вылетает с 
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView
 На MainFragment

Comment: На какой строчке вылетает?

Comment: view = inflater.inflate(getLayoutId(), container, false);

Comment: В приведённом коде такого не вижу.

Comment: Добавил код MainFragment

Comment: А почему бы вам просто там не поместить `R.layout.fragment_bill` вместо вызова какого-то метода?..

Comment: Компилятор выдает ошибку expected resource of type id

Comment: Ну... Приведите как вы написали...

Comment: Изменил xml вместо FrameLayout на ListView и поставил вместо android.R.id.list на R.layout.fragment_bill

Answer (score 1):

В вашем `R.layout.fragment_bill` нет `ListView`  с `id` `android.R.id.list`, который вы пытаетесь найти этой строчкой:

```
ListView list = (ListView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```